# React Router isn't rendering my component but does take me to new url path?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Can someone please show and explain where I am going wrong in here, I have used code structured like this in other projects and it has worked so not sure where the issue is.

When I click my button it changes to the new url path but does not render the new component.

Code Below:

App.js

```
import './App.css';

import LandingPage from '../src/Pages/LandingPage'

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import { MenuPage } from './Pages/MenuPage';



function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={LandingPage}/>
        <Route path="/menu" component={MenuPage}/>
      </Switch>

    </Router>
    
  );
}


export default App;
```

LandingPage.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Container from '../Components/Container';
import Img from '../Components/HangingLamp';
import Title from '../Components/Title';
import Wok from '../Components/Wok';
import {HomeButton, HomeButtonText} from '../Components/HomeButton';
import {Lamp, Lamp1} from '../Components/Lamp';
import  {Link} from "react-router-dom";


export const LandingPage = () => {

    
    return (
        <Container>
            <Img />
            <Lamp/>
            <Lamp1/>
            <Title>
                Authentic Asian Cuisine Delivered Straight To Your Door!
            </Title>
            <Wok/>
            <Link to="/menu">
                <HomeButton type="button"/>
            </Link>
            <HomeButtonText>
                Order Now!
            </HomeButtonText>
        </Container>
    )
}

export default LandingPage;
```

MenuPage.js

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Container from '../Components/Container'

export const MenuPage = () => {
    return (
        <Container>
            <MenuTitle>
                Our Menu
            </MenuTitle>

        </Container>
    )
}

const MenuTitle = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    width: 374px;
    height: 68px;
    left: 134px;
    top: 126px;

    font-family: Rosario;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 42px;
    line-height: 51px;
    text-align: center;
`
```

Comment: And Why are you doing two exports for a single component? 
export const LandingPage = () => {} and export default LandingPage. You can remove the export from the "export const Landing =() =>{}".

Comment: Did not even notice that! because I did the rafc shortcut I did not realise It automatically exports it - Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the order you are using your `Route` inside the switch statment. Change the order as below and it should work fine. Keep the specific Route to the top . Because when it tries to match `/menu` it finds a match with `/` and render that Route.

```
<Switch>
        <Route path="/menu">
          <p> Menu </p>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/">
          <p>home page </p>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
```

Comment: Cheers mate works perfect now, did not realis the order was suppose to be that way

Answer (score 0):

MenuPage is not the default export so it can't be fetched by the router

Comment: No, its not mandatory/rule that a component has to be default exported .

Comment: @Shyam, yes it's not mandatory that a component has to be default exported. But in the main component the user is not exporting the landing component as named export ( import {something} from "something" but import something from "something". that's why he has to default export the component.

Comment: he has exported it as `export const MenuPage ` and imported it as `import { MenuPage } from './Pages/MenuPage';`